# How to mock document.evaluate() and XPathResult in a mocha unit test?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, mocha.js, jsdom

I have following JavaScript class wrapping `document.evaluate()` selecting a DOM element using a XPath:

```
'use strict'
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true })
class ElementByXPath {
  constructor(elementXPath) {
    this.elementXPath = elementXPath
  }
  element(document) {
    return document.evaluate(
      this.elementXPath,
      document.documentElement,
      null,
      XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
      null,
    ).singleNodeValue
  }
}
exports.ElementByXPath = ElementByXPath
```

Following test written in `mocha` shall verify the method `element()`:

```
describe('ElementByXPath function test', () => {
  it('should return element of given XPath', () => {
    const dom = new JSDOM(`<p id = "test-id"/p>`)
    const result = new ElementByXpath('//*[@id="test-id"]').element(
      dom.window.document,
    )

    expect(result.tagName).to.equal('P')
  })
})
```

Using [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) I was able to mock the `window` element. Unfortunately, I cannot mock `XPathResult`:

```
ReferenceError: XPathResult is not defined
```

Has someone maybe a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `jsdom-global` next to `jsdom` (described [here](https://journal.artfuldev.com/unit-testing-node-applications-with-typescript-using-mocha-and-chai-384ef05f32b2)):

```
npm i -D jsdom jsdom-global
```

Register `jsdom-global` when `mocha` executes the tests

```
mocha -r jsdom-global/register test/**/*.test.js
```